# How to close command prompt on keyboard key down

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, command-line, console-application, command-prompt

I have a Command Prompt applocation which is doing some operation and at the end of the operation it displays some information to the user. So command prompt should not exit until user finish reading the message. Command prompt should only be closed on any keyboard key down event. How can I do this ?

Comment: is having a "Press any key to continue..." followed by a Console.ReadKey() too basic?

Comment: Thanks. I didnt expect this is so simple :). i'm not that familiar with command prompt apps

Comment: Or `Console.ReadLine()` if you want only Enter as the exit key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Will wait for a key to be pressed.